# Do $C_b(X)$ and $L^{\infty}(X)$ have the same duals?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I was reading the following theorem where $C_b(X)$ are the continuous and bounded function on $X$.

**Theorem** : Consider a normal topological space $X$ and a positive linear functional $\varphi\colon C_b(X)\to\mathbb{R}$. There exists a unique finitely additive set function $\mu$ defined on the algebra generated by the open sets in $X$ such that $$\varphi(f)=\int_X f\,d\mu,\quad f\in C_b(X).$$

So the dual of the $C_b(X)$ would be the finitely additive measure. But isn't this also the dual of $L^{\infty}(X)$? If it is the case, how can we explain that they have the same dual?

Comment: What is the meaning of $L^\infty(X)$, without reference to any measure?  Are you referring to the bounded, Borel measurable functions?  If so $L^\infty(X)$ is not a standard notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same!

- $C_b(X)'$ is the finitely additive measures defined on the **algebra** generated by opens,
- $L^\infty(X)'$ is the finitely additive measures defined on the **$\sigma$-algebra** generated by opens.

Comment: Thank you. Do you suggest a reference where the dual where it is shown that $L^\infty(X)'$ is the finitely additive measures defined on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by opens?

Comment: I'm assuming the measure is complete, otherwise it is messier to state.  See, for example, Dunford-Schwarz, *Linear Operators I* which goes into the noncomplete case too.  You also have entire book devoted to this and its consequences, e.g., [John Toland's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-34732-1).

Comment: perfect, thank you

Comment: Just a quick followup question : What would be a finitely additive measure defined on the algebra generated by opens that is not a finitely additive measure defined on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by opens?